# How do I close a put option when the company is about to file for bankruptcy?

Tags: options, put-options, selling, open-interest

I opened a put options by selling so I must buy to close. The company I have the open option position with is about to file for bankruptcy. How should I go about closing my put option. What's the worse that can happen?

Comment: What happens depends on what bankruptcy means.  It could be reorganization.  It could be that the company folds.  Either way, you're highly likely to incur the maximum loss on your short put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst: If the share price goes to zero, and the option gets exercised, you will (be forced to) buy 100 shares for the strike price. Then you turn around and discard them in the trash (selling them for zero costs a fee).
Your loss will be strike price times 100 (times the number of options you sold), minus what yo got paid when you sold them.

Comment: Okay Aganju. Thanks for replying.

Comment: So I had a $2.50 Strike price and I received a $100 credit when I sold to open. (250 - 100 = 150) So I would take a 150 dollar loss on top of what I already loss when the price of the stock dropped from $1.85 to .40 cents... Wow I'll be careful next time and research the company a little more. The financials were in the negative anyways for a few quarters as well as the cash flow and income statements.

Comment: There are three ways to 'close' an options position: Sell/buy, exercise or expiration. You are discussing the 'exercise' close, where the holder of your options will exercise them, forcing you to buy stock shares at the strike price. 'Expiration' option would be nice, but in this case there's almost no chance that the holder of your options will let them expire - he would miss out on his tidy profit. The third option is open to you at any time; you can 'buy to close' now. I.e. pay the options' market price, now, to buy the same number of options that you had previously sold.

Comment: @Orange Coast- reinstate Monica.  (1) All options expire.  The question is whether they expire ITM or OTM. (2) the OCC exercises options that are in-the-money by specified threshold amounts unless the clearing member submits instructions not to exercise these options. This is called Exercise By Exception.  While it is possible for an ITM option not to be assigned due to DNE orders, it's highly improbable.